# OneToMany domain class not saving in unit test

Tags: grails

I have a relation for an attributes table that works in my application but in the unit test, the save doesn't clear old values.

```
class Customer {
  static hasMany = [customerAttributes: CustomerAttribute]
  static mapping = {
    customerAttributes cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
  }

  // other properties...
}

class CustomerAttribute implements Serializable {
  Long id
  String attributeName
  String attributeValue
  Customer customer

  static mapping = {
    id generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'cust_attribute_seq']
    version false
  }

  static belongsTo [customer: Customer]
}

class CustomerController {
  def updateAttributes(Customer customer, Map values) {
    // Keep same Set reference for hibernate
    customer.customerAttributes.clear()

    // Logic to update customerAttributes not used in remove test...
  }
}
```

In my test, I can see that the update logic removes the old attributes but after saving and refreshing the attributes still exist. The reason I'm trying to test the domain update is because the code previously changed the set but wasn't defined with cascade so was broken and the save will fail if the set reference is lost.

```
class CustomerControllerSpec extends Specification
        implements ControllerUnitTest<CustomerController>, DataTest {

  def setupSpec() {
    mockDomains(
        Customer, CustomerAttribute
    )
  }


  def "test updateAttributes remove"() {
    given:
    Customer customer = new Customer().save()

    new CustomerAttribute(
      attributeName: 'ATTR_TO_REMOVE',
      attributeValue: 'test_remove',
      customer: customer,
    ).save()


    when:
    controller.updateAttributes(customer, [:]) // no attributes

    then:
    customer.customerAttributes.size() == 0

    when:
    customer.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

    then:
    // THIS FAILS. size() == 1
    CustomerAttribute.findAllByCustomer(customer).size() == 0
  }
}
```

Why would the save work when running the application but fail in the unit test?